# Find common values in two text files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Let me give the example text files:

e.g. in `file1.txt` the data the first three columns are the coordinates x y z:

```
3.6 2.5  0.0 1 c321    
3.0 2.5  0.0 2 c23a
2.4 3.4 10.8 3 cf17
3.6 3.4  6.6 4 bd11
```

in `file2.txt` the data the first two columns is:

```
c321
bd11    
bc2d    
cf17
```

Desired result:

```
c321 3.6 2.5 0.0    
bd11 3.6 3.4 6.6    
bc2d    
cf17 2.4 3.4 10.8
```

Comment: I have two text file that contains shared values and I want for each common values it displays their coordinated

Comment: He (@Clodion) meant if you have tried it yourself? Post your code and the community can help.

Comment: @oualid walid: My question is where are your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If  c321,bd11  etc.. cannot repeat just use a dict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    d = OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(str.rstrip, f2),"")
    for line in f1:
        if line.strip():
            data,k = line.rsplit(None, 1)
            if k in d:
                d[k] = data

for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
c321 3.6 2.5 0.0 1
bd11 3.6 3.4 6.6 4
bc2d 
cf17 2.4 3.4 10.8 3
```

If you actually have two columns per row i.e:

```
c321 bd11
bc2d cf17
```

The you need to split the lines to get each key:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    d = OrderedDict((k, "") for line in f2 for k in line.split())
    for line in f1:
        if line.strip():
            data, k = line.rsplit(None, 1)
            if k in d:
                d[k] = data
```

Comment: How do you mean two columns, there is only one in your example input?

Comment: So there are actually two columns per row?

Comment: I edited my example now you are can see two columns in the file 2

Comment: Thank you Padraic for your patience

Comment: @oualidwalid : Next time please put all relevant information in first version of your question. You loosed time to get a correct answer and Padraic Cunningham losed time answering an incorrect question.

Comment: @oualidwalid. I still don't get the input example, are you saying you have empty columns?

Comment: no she is not an empty columns
Columns 1 contains the principal values
and columns 2 contains the secondary values

Comment: Padraic Cunningham I need your help